# What is the most precise definition of майдан?

Tags: переклад, from-english

My grandmother says that in a phrase it is "a big field where people gather", but I can't think  of a more succinct way to express this idea. Google translate says "public square", but to me this implies an urban setting.

Comment: Unfortunately, asking about translations **to** other languages is off-topic ([suggested on Meta](https://ukrainian.meta.stackexchange.com/a/178/8)). However, this question can be easily salvaged if it asked about the *etymology* and the origin of the word. P.S. `/meidan/` is "square, big area" in many Turkic languages, incl. Crimean Tatar.

Comment: @FracturedRetina Yes, it’s urban setting, because here [_майдан_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maidan) is the _main [central] square_ in a city (not always or more correct — not anywhere). Other squares are defined as _площа_ — just _a square_. But _Майдан_ also can mean _a meeting of a big number of people_ at this _maidan_ for solving political problems. Famous maidan: [Majdan Nezaležnosti](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maidan_Nezalezhnosti)

Comment: [Here](http://slovopedia.org.ua/34/53407/33168.html) you can read personal opinion of [Borys Antonenko-Davydovych](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%BE-%D0%94%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87_%D0%91%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81_%D0%94%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87) for the meaning of this word

Comment: In fact, _майдан_ **doesn't necessarily mean urban setting**. Originally it's really an open place where people gather (see [майдан](http://sum.in.ua/s/majdan) in dictionary; or famous poem [«Останнє прохання старого лірника»](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/Останнє_прохання_старого_лірника) a.k.a. «[Переведіть мене через майдан](//www.youtube.com/watch?v=jIPJM48p4MY)» (more known due to the appearance of its Russian translation as a song in a film, but being originally Ukrainian)). However in minds of modern urban citizens the word really more associates with urban setting (they can't imagine other).

Answer (score 5):

As Sasha already mentioned, the [dictionary](http://sum.in.ua/s/majdan) known as SUM-11 defines майдан as:

1. An open area without buildings in a city or in a village; a square. // area where a Bazar is situated (this can be even outside of the city).
2. Same as майданчик (small area for building (будівельний майданчик), sport activity (спортивний майданчик), dance floor (танцювальний майданчик), etc.
3. In some dialects - forest glade
4. (etc.)

So, as you can see, there is no true "urban" bindings here. Possibly this feeling about this word can be explained by the fact that "the main" square of the country is called Майдан Незалежності (while most other squares are "площа") and that many state-wide influential events happened there.

However (as Yola noticed), Borys Antonenko-Davydovych [thought](http://slovopedia.org.ua/34/53407/33168.html) that майдан should be used instead of the word площа in all non-mathematical meanings (I guess in English it would be area for площа and square for майдан).

Comment: А чому «However»? Твердження Антоненка-Давидовича (якщо припустити, що воно правильне) же не забирає в слова «майдан» можливості застосування до сільских майданів, а, навпаки, ще більше розширює сферу його вжитку. Я б сказав, «additionally» (або навіть «and even more — …»), але не редагую, бо міг не до кінця зрозуміти хід Ваших думок.

Comment: However відноситься до попереднього абзацу ("на відміну від урбаністичного відчуття, описаного у попередньому абзаці - це не так").